# python subclase dentro de otra subclase

Tags: python

hola estoy estudiando el funcionamiento de las clases y herencia en python , y al tratar de crear pequeños programas como ejercicios para probar la teoria . no consigo que el programa funcione .
¿es posible crear una subclase dentro de otra subclase , que herede los atributos de la clase padre principal y de la subclase hija ? 
¿o por el contrario solo es posible subclases a partir de la clase padre principal ?

he incluido el codigo para mejor comprension.
cracias por su ayuda .

```
class padre(object):
###Este es el constructor de atributos  de la clase padre
  def __init__(self,p1,p2,p3):
    self.p1 = p1
    self.p2 = p2
    self.p3 = p3

  def funcion_metodo_clase_padre_1(self):
    print self.p1,"Ejecuta una funcion/método de clase padre"

  def funcion_metodo_clase_padre_2(self):
    print self.p2,"Ejecuta una funcion/método de clase padre"

p1 = 2
p2 = 4
p3 = 6

###padre(2,4,6)

class hija(padre):
  def __init__(self,p1,p2,p3,h1,h2):
      padre.__init__(self,p1,p2,p3)
      self.h1 = h1
      self.h2 = h2

  def funcion_metodo_clase_hija_1(self):
        print self.p1,"metodo hija"

h1 = 3
h2 = 5      

hija = hija(p1,p2,p3,h1,h2)     
hija.funcion_metodo_clase_padre_1()
hija.funcion_metodo_clase_padre_2()
hija.funcion_metodo_clase_hija_1()

class nieta(hija):
  def __init__(self,p1,p2,p3,h1,h2,n1,n2):
      hija.__init__(self,p1,p2,p3,h1,h2)
      self.n1 = n1
      self.n2 = n2

  def funcion_metodo_clase_nieta_1(self):
        print self.p1,"metodo nieta"

n1 = 10
n2 = 20      

nieta = nieta(p1,p2,p3,h1,h2,n1,n2)     
nieta.funcion_metodo_clase_nieta_1()
```

este es el error que me da al compilar:

> ```
> 2 Ejecuta una funcion/método de clase padre
> 4 Ejecuta una funcion/método de clase padre
> 2 metodo hija
>
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "python", line 54, in <module>
>     TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>         __init__() takes exactly 6 arguments (4 given)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Por supuesto que Python soporta la herencia multi-nivel. Tu problema no tiene nada que ver con eso, **simplemente estas sobreescribiendo las clases con sus instancias**.

Hacer esto:

```
hija = hija(p1,p2,p3,h1,h2)
```

implica que ahora el nombre `hija` no apunta a una clase sino una instancia de ella. No debes hacer esto, deberias hacer algo como:

```
inst_hija =  hija(p1,p2,p3,h1,h2)
```

No obstante, un par de convenciones que deberias seguir para evitar problemas de este tipo:

- Se recomienda nombrar las clases empezando por mayúscula.
- Usa siempre 4 espacios para identar entre cada nivel. No debes usar tabulaciones y jamás mezcles espcaios con tabulaciones.

Mirate [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) para más información.

Tu código deberia ser algo así:

```
class Padre(object):
    def __init__(self,p1,p2,p3):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p3 = p3

    def funcion_metodo_clase_padre_1(self):
        print self.p1,"Ejecuta una funcion/método de clase padre"

    def funcion_metodo_clase_padre_2(self):
        print self.p2,"Ejecuta una funcion/método de clase padre"



class Hija(Padre):
    def __init__(self,p1,p2,p3,h1,h2):
        Padre.__init__(self, p1,p2,p3)
        self.h1 = h1
        self.h2 = h2

    def funcion_metodo_clase_hija_1(self):
        print self.p1,"metodo hija"



class Nieta(Hija):
    def __init__(self, p1,p2,p3,h1,h2,n1,n2):
        Hija.__init__(self,p1,p2,p3,h1,h2)
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2

    def funcion_metodo_clase_nieta_1(self):
        print self.p1,"metodo nieta"

p1 = 2
p2 = 4
p3 = 6
h1 = 3
h2 = 5
n1 = 10
n2 = 20  

hija = Hija(p1,p2,p3,h1,h2)     
hija.funcion_metodo_clase_padre_1()
hija.funcion_metodo_clase_padre_2()
hija.funcion_metodo_clase_hija_1()
nieta = Nieta(p1,p2,p3,h1,h2,n1,n2)     
nieta.funcion_metodo_clase_nieta_1()
nieta.funcion_metodo_clase_padre_1()
```

En tu caso llamas explicitamente al método `__init__` del padre, otra opción es usar `super()`que se encarga de llamar al inicializador del padre automáticamente:

```
class Hija(Padre):
    def __init__(self,p1,p2,p3,h1,h2):
        super(Hija, self).__init__(p1,p2,p3)
        self.h1 = h1
        self.h2 = h2

    def funcion_metodo_clase_hija_1(self):
        print self.p1,"metodo hija"



class Nieta(Hija):
    def __init__(self, p1,p2,p3,h1,h2,n1,n2):
        super(Nieta, self).__init__(p1,p2,p3,h1,h2)
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2

    def funcion_metodo_clase_nieta_1(self):
        print self.p1,"metodo nieta"
```

De todas formas, el verdadero potencial de `super` se obtiene con herencia múltiple.